# Tab Control not firing system events

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

This is for WinForms.

I am having a strange problem that is driving me absolutely batty.  I have a tab control for which standard system events, and only standard system events, are not firing.  The specific event I was trying to get to fire was the TabIndexChanged event.  It doesn't matter whether I add this programmatically or with the designer.

Note: Mouse events will fire.  Keypress events will fire.  All other events that I have tried will fire.

System events on OTHER controls will fire.

It isn't a single tab control that is having a problem either.  If I drag a new tab control onto the form it will also have this problem.

I do not really have any code to show here because it would just be the event as generated by the designer and a Console.WriteLine message to see if it is firing (this line outputs for other events).  What I am hoping for is some insight as to what could cause this problem.

The entire program is quite large, so I cannot really clip the whole thing into this forum so that individuals can hunt for a specific problem.  My hope is that somebody might be able to point me to what might cause this behavior.  I am thinking that maybe something got screwed up when editing in design mode, but I just do not know what to look for.  I am relatively new to C# and programming is a hobby for me.

Thank you for your time,

FC

Comment: Have you tried the `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead of the `TabIndexChanged`? The later gets fired when the VALUE of the tab index property is changed.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you.  I feel silly, but I had spent a day trying to figure out why this wasn't firing.  I have no idea what actually fires with the tab index event then, but your solution does what I want.

Comment: The event `TabIndexChange` gets fired when you change the `TabIndex` of the `TabControl`. Like `tabControl1.TabIndex = 7` will fire this event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try the property SelectedIndexChanged; to expose that property, with the property window open, click once outside the tabbed container then click one of the small tabs once, don't click inside the tab area. Find the property, type in an event name and then double click it.

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed it!